# dataDetectorTypes sometime hyperlinking the all the text

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have setup my TextView to look for hyperlinks as such:

```
commentText.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Sometimes, this works great, finding the links in my text and making the appropriate hyperlinks. Sometimes however, it will select all the text in the screen even if there isn't a hyperlink in the text. Has anyone ever encountered this problem or know how to use this properly?

Thanks,

- Collin

Answer (score 0):

Once i had the problem, it was when i was using cells and the reuse on the cells was making this bug

So i had to override preparetoreuse like this to reset the settings

```
- (void)prepareForReuse
{
    _bodyTextView.editable = YES;
    _bodyTextView.editable = NO;
    _bodyTextView.font = fontText;
    _bodyTextView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:MyStyle(@"todayFontColorText")];
}
```

Hope it kinda help...